# How to Access variable and functions of any class in a different class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
import copy

class Myclass0:
    paperlist=[]
class Myclass1:
    def copy_something(self):
        Paper = Myclass0()
        Flowers = ["Roses","Sunflower","Tulips","Marigold"]
        Paper.paperlist = copy.copy(Flowers)
class Myclass3:
    superlist = []
    Paper = Myclass0()
    print(Paper.paperlist)
    superlist.append(paperlist[0])
```

I am getting a index out of range error on compiling.please help me finding a way to print **paperlist** of **Myclass0** in **Myclass3** using class **Myclass1** Functions and attributes.You can change the class body but **All the Classes should be used**.

I am waiting for your valuable efforts.

**Thank You**

Comment: are you aware that you are actually assigning class-attributes? https://www.python-course.eu/python3_class_and_instance_attributes.php

Comment: In `Myclass0` you define `paperlist` as a class atrribute. With `Paper.paperlist = copy.copy(Flowers)` you set an instance attribute that doesn't change `Myclass0.paperlist`.

Comment: This code doesn't give an "index out of range" error and the code in `Myclass1` is never called.

Comment: This code doesn't give error as the person explained.

Comment: This code runs successfully. Output will be an empty list.

Comment: Why do you use the `copy` lib?

Comment: Thank You developers for replying very faster the problem is when i use the paperlist somewhere else like list1.append(paperlist[0]) then it is giving out index out of range error because it is empty.

Comment: @Matthias can you please explain me more about this i think this is the problem what i am searching for

Comment: Please clarify: Do you know the difference between class attributes and instance attributes and if "yes", do you really want `paperlist` to be a class attribute?

Comment: @Matthias i am very sorry but i don't know the difference please help me out i am stuck

Comment: In `Myclass3` your code is `Paper = Myclass0()`. You create a new instance of `Myclass0` here. Why do you expect it to have magically appear something in `datalist`?

Comment: @Matthias Because after i call the function copy_something() in Myclass1 i expected it to copy the content of list Flowers to the paperlist of Myclass0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this code snippet could help you understand it better:

```
class MyClass0:
    def __init__(self):
        # this is now an attribute of the instance (not the class)
        self.paperlist = []


class MyClass1:

    @staticmethod
    def copy_something(paper):
        # this is a static method (it doesnt rely on the Class (MyClass1) or an instance of it
        flowers = ["Roses", "Sunflower", "Tulips", "Marigold"]
        paper.paperlist = flowers


class Myclass3:
    def __init__(self, paper):
        # when an instance of this class is created an instance of MyClass0
        # must pre passed to its constructor. It then prints out its paperlist
        print(paper.paperlist)


paper = MyClass0()
MyClass1.copy_something(paper)
Myclass3(paper)
```

Comment: By this code you have created the instance paper in last 3 lines of code this means that this instance is global and can be used everywhere

Comment: thats correct but the code does not rely on that. You can easily copy those 3 lines into another (non global) scope.